# Using Limit random on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, random, limit

I just used this query

```
SELECT * FROM questions 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20;
```

On mysql database I have a column called display (along with the  columns of questions)  where the values are equal to 1.So now as you can see in the query I have limited to 20.I want to change the value of the all the 20 to display=0.I know this is the query

```
update test3
set display=0
where id=11;
```

But this just sets the display of one row.How do I do it for the 20.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this

```
update test3
set display=0 
where id in (select id from questions order by rand() limit 20);
```

Suppose you are using php.

```
$result = msyql_query("select id from questions order by rand() limit 20");

$ids = array();

while($row = msyql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $ids[] = $row['id'];  
}
```

For your condition, first perform the first query and save the ids from the first query.

Suppose you are using php and you have saved the ids from the first query in `$ids`;

you can run the second query like this;

```
$idstring = implode(',',$ids);

$query = 'update test3 set display=0 where id in ('.$idstring.' )';

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: I am sure this will work.But wont work for me,I will tell you why.See once I exectue the first query in my example I need to display it and then I need to put a 0 in display column for that id.Because between the 2 queries in my question above I use a if statement where I say if display=1, display the question.so I need to use the queries seperately so if there is another way possible.

Comment: I really dont know php nor I know mysql properly(just know to create and CRUD the database),so if it would be possible for you to tell me how to save the ids after my first query?

Comment: any idea how to do it with java?

Comment: I dont know how to do it in java.

Comment: As I told you I dont understand php,dont even know where do I add this code.Anyways thanks for the help,But if possible I would prefer in java or pure mysql..thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

Use the `WHERE` clause to search a subquery

```
UPDATE test3
SET display = 0
WHERE id IN (
SELECT id FROM questions 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20)
```

If you want to perform something between the `SELECT` and the `UPDATE` try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (
    division TINYINT
)

INSERT INTO #Temp 
SELECT id FROM questions 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20

--SELECT * FROM #Temp

UPDATE test3
SET display = 0
WHERE id IN (
SELECT division FROM #Temp)
```

Comment: I am sure this will work.But wont work for me,I will tell you why.See once I exectue the first query in my example I need to display it and then I need to put a 0 in display column for that id.Because between the 2 queries in my question above I use a if statement where I say if display=1, display the question.so I need to use the queries seperately so if there is another way possible.

Comment: Please see my edit and see if that works for you. Note I am not 100% familiar with the dynamics of TempTables in MySQL but I don't think T-SQL is that different.

Comment: Thanks for the help.But I dont get the above query.I will be writing this in java so I dont know how I will write it.Anyways thnx for the help.

Comment: We are creating a temporary table (you can modify this to store the entire contents of `questions`). We then store the division id into the temp table. This allows us to do whatever we want to `test3` without regenerating random id's because the temp table will have what we selected earlier.